# Good library for using TDD with MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, tdd, nunit

Building a new website at work and I'm trying to learn some TDD so that it can be implemented from the beginning on the new website (old site was plain asp pages with zero testing).  However, since I'm new to TDD I have no clue what some good libraries to use are.  I've already ran into issues trying to design tests...  For example one of my controllers uses `Server.MapPath()` and consequently is currently failing.  Trying to find a solid library that has been built well.  I've googled and found an option or two, but have no clue what people that are already using TDD are using.  Since I have (want) to learn this I'd just assume learn it with a library that others are using with success.

EDIT: Sorry I am currently using NUnit to do the tests in, but I'm open to other libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) for automated testing, [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)/[RhinoMocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks) for mocking/stubbing, [Team City](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) for continuous integration. I personally prefer Moq, but you should give both of those a try.

To deal with ASP.NET, there are some extensions for NUnit. For example, the one [this guy describes](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NUnitUnitTestingOfASPNETPagesBaseClassesControlsAndOtherWidgetryUsingCassiniASPNETWebMatrixVisualStudioWebDeveloper.aspx). There is already a question about NUnit and web applications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175400/nunit-and-web-applications)

Comment: Thanks I had searched on SO for nunit + mappath which is the specific problem I'm having atm, but that's mainly due to not being super far into development at this point.

Comment: In that case, you might want to take a look at NUnitASP and Cassini

Answer (score 1):

You may find this [MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490346.aspx) "Behavior-Driven Development with SpecFlow and WatiN" interesting.

Answer (score 0):

NUnit with NUnit.Snippets Nuget package.

http://nuget.org/packages/NUnit.Snippets

In order to create testable application you will have to use Dependency Injection throughout whole code base or use some other patterns to be able to change implementations (for example the one you mentioned using Server.MapPath) during testing. To use DI you will need DI Container and your custom controller factory.